# How so I make the background of the page red, after the counter reaches zero?

Tags: javascript

This is my code and it runs, but I have to change the background color to red when the counter reaches zero.

```
  <script>
    window.onload = function () {
      const tag = document.getElementById("tag1");
      var time = 100;
      const getTime = ()=>{
        time = time - 1;
        tag.innerHTML = "Goodbye Aliens: ship leaves in " + time + " secs ";
      }
        setInterval(getTime, 500);
    }
  </script>

  <body>
    <div>
      <h1 id="tag1">Hello Earthling</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
  
  <script>
    const tag = document.getElementById("tag1");
    tag.innerHTML = "Goodbye Aliens";
  </script>
</html>
```

I thought of something like this in order to do it:

```
function changeColor() {
    if (time == 0) {
        document.change.bgColor = "red";
}
}
```

but it does not work and I do not understand where to put the code in the first place.
Please explain if someone has time. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried calling the `changeColor`  within the `getTime` method, such that it is executed periodically?

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to check the time variable inside the `GetTime` method and calling `changeColor` when its 0.

Then you need to clear the interval using `clearInterval` to stop the loop.

```js
function changeColor() {
    document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

window.onload = function () {
  const tag = document.getElementById("tag1");
  var time = 10;
  const getTime = () =>{
    time = time - 1;
    tag.innerHTML = "Goodbye Aliens: ship leaves in " + time + " secs ";
    if(time === 0){
      changeColor();
      window.clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }
    var interval = setInterval(getTime, 500);
}
    
    
const tag = document.getElementById("tag1");
tag.innerHTML = "Goodbye Aliens";
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 id="tag1">Hello Earthling</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Your way was the easiest for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tend to favour [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) over `setInterval`. It seems more managable.

Note: I've used a class here instead of directly setting the style on the element.

```js
const tag = document.getElementById('tag1');

// `getTime` accepts a time argument which 
// we initialise as 100
function getTime(time = 100) {

  // Print the message using `textContent` rather than `innerHTML`
  tag.textContent = `Goodbye Aliens: ship leaves in ${time} secs`;

  // If time reaches 0 set the background to red using a class
  if (time === 0) {
    tag.classList.add('red');

  // Otherwise call `getTime` again passing in a decremented
  // `time` value as the argument
  } else {
    setTimeout(getTime, 50, --time);
  }
}

// Call `getTime` after showing the initial message
setTimeout(getTime, 2000);
```

```css
.red { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<div>
  <h3 id="tag1">Hello Earthling</h3>
</div>
```